# Woocommerce 2.6 API v1 -> Invalid parameter

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm trying to add products to Woocommerce with the Wordpress API  as per https://github.com/woothemes/wc-api-php

I am using the Wordpress API  /wp-json/wc/v1

This is my data

```
Array
(
    [type] => simple
    [name] => Bike
    [regular_price] => 300
    [description] => This is a new bike
)
```

Then I do  `$woocommerce->post('products',$data);`

But the regular_price won't work.  Without it it works fine,  when I add it I get errors like

*Invalid parameter regular_price [rest_invalid_param]*

Not sure if this is the exact error,  translated it from Dutch

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Solved! 
regular_price has to be a string, I assigned a integer to it

Changed

`$wcProduct['regular_price'] = $moxPart->price;`

to

`$wcProduct['regular_price'] = (string)$moxPart->price;`